# mouseover hover in Gridview ASP.net using CSS not working

Tags: css, asp.net

I have Css gridview like this below. I try to make a hover on it. But it's not working i some rows

```
  <style type="text/css">
        .gridview
        {
            font-family: "arial";
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: small;
        }
        .gridview th
        {
            background: #7AC142;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: small;
        }
        .gridview th a
        {
            color: #003300;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .gridview td
        {
            background: #D9EDC9;
            color: #333333;
            font: small "arial";
            padding: 4px;
        }
        .gridview tr.even td
        {
            background: #FFFFFF;
        }
        .rows
        {
            background-color: #fff;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #000;
            min-height: 25px;
            text-align: left;
            border: none 0px transparent;
        }
        .rows:hover td
        {
            background-color: #ff8000;
            font-family: Arial;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .selectedrow
        {
            background-color: #ff8000;
            font-family: Arial;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .gridview td a:hover
        {
            background-color: #ff8000;
            font-family: Arial;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
```

And below is my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAsset" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" CssClass="gridview" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="even"
    runat="server" OnRowCommand="gvAsset_RowCommand" EmptyDataText="No Record Available"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="False" DataKeyNames="Asset_ID"
    Width="100%" OnSorting="gvAsset_Sorting" OnRowDataBound="gvAsset_RowDataBound">
    <RowStyle />
    <AlternatingRowStyle />
    <HeaderStyle />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanel2" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" CommandName="EditRow" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Asset_ID") %>'
                            runat="server">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="True" DataField="Asset_ID" SortExpression="Asset_ID" HeaderText="ID"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></PagerStyle>
</asp:GridView>
```

My css hover is working in the first row, but not in the second row. Then the third row is working but not the fourth row and so on. (It's not working in the even row) I'm not good in CSS I try already change the hover or td from one row of css code to another row of css code but it still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `.rows:hover td` to

```
.rows:hover td, .even:hover td
{
    background-color: #ff8000 !important;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
}
```

The `!important` after background color is nessecary because you set a white background in `.gridview tr.even td`.